# Get selected value in jquery script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a list of elements which are gotten from a xml file and I write them down in a table. In every row, I have a form which send the input field values to a jquery script, but it always pass the first value of the table, Does anyone knows how to pass the selected value?

This is my html and php code:

```
<?php 
    $licenseElement  = ""; 
foreach ($xml->xpath("/Resultado/Registro") as $licenseElement):?>


<form>
<input type="hidden" id="desactivate" name="desactivate" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo   $licenseElement->nombre; ?>" />

<input type='button' value='Desactivate'  onclick='myCallDesactivate(desactivate,name);' />
    </form> 
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

And this is the jquery script:

```
   <script>                         
        function myCallDesactivate(desactivate,name) {

            var val1 = $('#desactivate').val();

            var val2 = $('#name').val();

                var request = $.ajax({
                    url: "mypage.php",
                    data: { desactivate: val1, name: val2 },
                    type: "POST",           
                    dataType: "html"
                });
                request.done(function(msg) {
                    $("#mybox2").html(msg);         
                });
                request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                });
            }   
            }

    </script>
```

Comment: How is a value selected? Do you have multiple elements with the same id? What is the `desactivate` and `name` in the onclick? They should be strings??

Comment: these are parameters to be passed to mypage.php page. The values are passed calling the function in the input button.